# JSF trimming white spaces

Tags: jsf, whitespace, trim

HI,

I have an input field in which I want to trim any leading/trailing whitespaces. We are using JSF and binding the input field to a backing bean in the jsp using:

```
<h:inputText id="inputSN" value="#{regBean.inputSN}" maxlength="10"/>
```

My question is that besides validation can this be done in the jsp? I know we can also do this using the trim() java function in the Handler, but just wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve this in JSF.

Thanks.

Comment: I resolved this by just using the trim() function in the handler before doing any processing. Thanks for the alternate idea though McDowell.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a [Converter](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) ([tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaus.html)).

Comment: And register it with `converter-for-class` for `java.lang.String` so that you don't need to define it on every `UIInput` component.

Comment: @Martlark - it is an element used in `faces-config.xml`. From spec: _/faces-config/converter -- Create or replace a converter id/converter class or target class/converter class pair with the Application instance for this web application._ Also: _The “converter-for-class” element represents the fully qualified class name for which a Converter class will be registered._ See the JSF specification for more.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by McDowell and BalusC, you can create a Converter, and register it with @FacesConvert annotation for the String class. And then in the getAsObject method check the UIComponent type and apply the trimming only for the HtmlInputText components.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = String.class)
public class StringTrimConverter implements Serializable, javax.faces.convert.Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent cmp, String value) {

        if (value != null && cmp instanceof HtmlInputText) {
            // trim the entered value in a HtmlInputText before doing validation/updating the model
            return value.trim();
        }

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent cmp, Object value) {

        if (value != null) {
            // return the value as is for presentation
            return value.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Or, if you don't feel like coding it yourself, see http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/TrimConverter

Comment: I personally feel THE ABOVE COMMENT should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385337/trimming-inputs-in-jboss-seam/3758887#3758887)

Basically you can either create your own component that is a copy of inputText which automatically trims, or you can extend the inputText and add `trim` attribute that trims if true.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by just using the trim() function in the handler before doing any processing. it just seemed like the most straight forward way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

```
public String getTexto() {
    return texto != null ? texto.trim() : null;
}
```