# How can i trim string in jsf xhtml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

How can i trim string with
`onblur="this.value=jQuery.trim(this.value)"/>` or with some else?

```
<h:form id="form" styleClass="edit">
            <c:forEach var="component" items="${categoryEdit.components}">
                <ui:include src="#{component.url}">
                    <ui:param name="component" value="#{component}"
onblur="this.value=jQuery.trim(this.value)"/>
                </ui:include>
            </c:forEach>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: or try top make a replace this.value.replace('/s+/gmi', '');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF trimming white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030086/jsf-trimming-white-spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on web try following note,

Interface Converter

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html

Creating a Custom Converter

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaus.html