# Unable to use FacesConverter

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I tried to use `FacesConverter` in Oracle ADF by following the thread

- [Why does <h:inputText required="true"> allow blank spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326398/why-does-hinputtext-required-true-allow-blank-spaces)

But, I was not able to import `FacesConverter` into my custom converter class.

Do I need to add any specific library to import `FacesConverter`?

Comment: Do you have javax.faces.jsf-api in you classpath?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to -

```
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
```

--Peddi

Comment: The OP is asking about a *library*, not about using it.